# How to get text and cell value using choose function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 option button from `form control` foo, bar, baz. If I write the formula `=CHOOSE($K1,C2,"baa", "bee")` and toggle foo , value from C2 pops up. If I toggle bar, `"baa"` shows up and for baz `"bee"` shows up.

Is there a way for me to concatenate C2 with a text value - such that when I click foo, I would be able to get something like , `"value of C2 is "` in one cell and in the next cell `[value of cell C2]`. It is something akin to Python's usage of concatenation operation, `print("this is two",2).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenation in excel is `=CONCATENATE("VALUE OF C2 = ", C2, " AND C3 = ", C3)`

If youre in vba you can simply use `"&"` or `"+"` to concatenate strings.

Comment: `&` can also be used to concatenate in formulas.

Comment: Neat I did not know this